# Should magazine names be written in italics?

Tags: italics

should they be in italics like books and newspapers?
I know about the latter but what about foreign magazines?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Whichever reference told you to italicize book and newspaper titles would *probably* have you italicize the titles of all serials, including magazines, newsletters, and journals. Can you explain why you think magazines would be an exception, or why foreign magazine titles would be an exception?

Comment: Generally speaking, any "proper name" of a publication is somehow made special, using italics, underlining, or quotation marks.  The method used depends on the typographic facilities available and the preferences of the editors for whom you are writing, but italics is pretty much standard these days, unless there is some technical limitation.

Answer (score 1):

Magazine titles in general should be italicized. Foreign words and phrases should be italicized unless they are widely used and understood that they have become a part of the English language.

You can find more information here: http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/italics.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you are a newspaper, you generally do not italicize magazine titles (AP style). If you are a magazine or a book, you generally do (Chicago style, among others). There is no right or wrong about this--the decision may be based on practical issues (the way type used to be set) or aesthetic considerations.